# Your Microsoft account needs to be repaired - strange mail address

Tags: windows-10

I got the message earlier today that my Microsoft account needs to be repaired, so I took a look at it, and when I click on "Jetzt beheben" (I assume the english term would be "Repair now"), it asks me for a password. But for an email address I have never seen in my life (`berinchik****@mail.ru`). When I click on E-Mail & Accounts, it shows 3 mail addresses, all of which are legitimately mine, now the question is, where is that russian mail address coming from? How can I find what the source of that is? I did a complete virus scan, came up empty.

Edit: the popup was from my Windows Infocenter, and the account was when I clicked on the System Panel and on "Repair now". No email, no webbrowser.

Comment: "I got the message" …where from? This just sounds like a phishing attempt, social engineering to trap the unwary.

Comment: Where did the message come from? Was it an email? Did you click on any links contained in the message (sounds like you did)? If you did, you should now assume your PC is infected with malware.

Comment: No, it was a Windows popup. From the infocenter saying something's not right with my MS account.

Answer (score 2):

Hackers maintain large repositories of email addresses,
and your email address is apparently now stocked by some
hacker group. This has nothing to do with your computer,
so it doesn't indicate that your computer is infected.
You should be from now on extremely wary of strange
email messages asking you to sign on for all sorts of reasons,
and never click on a link in an email without
being 100% sure of the sender.

Some of the world's best hackers are Russians, so a `.ru` address
should be extremely alarming for you. By going on that website,
you may have signaled the hackers that you exist and are willing to
click links.

I advise you to delete this email and ignore it. If you are worried
about your Microsoft account, verify it on `microsoft.com`, by
entering the address manually into the browser's address bar.
It's good practice for all emails asking you to click on a link,
to get there yourself using addresses that you know, rather than
by clicking links.

Comment: Why did you downvote this answer? I was only trying to help.

Comment: No idea who downvoted it. What I don't understand is why that mail pops up on my system at all.

Comment: The fact that my email is known somewhere... well, I guess most are? But I would love to get rid of that "Repair your MS account now", since its not even my account causing an issue.

Comment: I get several such emails every day. There is no way to avoid it, except having a good spam filter and being extremely careful. Changing the email address, besides being annoying, is a limited-time solution. It will only get worse with time, since hacker groups sell email databases.

Comment: It wasn't a spam / phishing mail. It was my actual windows infocenter popping up the info. Also the account recovery is when using the system panel, not some email / website.

Comment: I'm still worried about the `.ru` address. Keep on being very careful. Many of my spam messages originate from Russia.